# Strange crash with exceptions

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When debugging a C++ program in VS 2013, I get a crash (technically a "breakpoint") in an exception handler (catch block) after an exception is thrown. The following is from the Output window after it happens:

> First-chance exception at 0x75E54878 in Program.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00C6EE24.
>
> First-chance exception at 0x75E54878 in Program.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: ComException at memory location 0x00C6EF04.
>
> First-chance exception at 0x75E54878 in Program.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
>
> HEAP[Program.exe]: HEAP: Free Heap block 00FAB5A8 modified at 00FAB5D4 after it was freed
>
> Program.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

I tweaked the code to find the cause and got it to the point that it does something as simple as displaying a message box. Something like:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (const Exception&)
{
    ::MessageBox(NULL, L"Error", L"Error", 0); // <-- Crash happens here,
                                               // BEFORE the message box is displayed
}
```

The message from the Output window suggests that I'm trying to write to freed/invalid memory, but as you can see from this code snippet, that's not the case - I'm not even using variables at the time the crash happens.

Another strange thing is that, after the crash, the Call Stack window shows frames that were already unwound due to the exception, as if the call stack got "rebuilt".

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Present a **complete but minimal example** that readers can try. For now voting to close as lacking such reproducible example. Anyway, it's a good idea to use standard library exceptions, instead of e.g. MFC `Exception`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Uhm, if I could reproduce the problem in a small example, I'd already know what the problem is...

Comment: @user1610015 *I could reproduce the problem in a small example, I'd already know what the problem is*  -- So you expect us to figure out what the problem is given a one line catch block?  Also, what you're showing us is where your program finally breaks down -- it isn't where the problem originated.  The `MessageBox` call is a red-herring, as your program has already been compromised.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Same thing buddy, if I knew where the problem originated, I'd know what the problem is. I gave as much context and information as was available to me. I know it's a long shot, but maybe someone else has encountered the same problem and knows the solution.

Comment: @user1610015 Since you can't reproduce this with a small example, you are in a **much** better position to solve this issue than anyone here.  You have the entire source code, the debugger, the input used, etc.  Also, why are you not `catch`-ing the `_com_error` exceptions?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The _com_error happens in a library I'm using, and never reaches my code (the exception I deal with is an unrelated ComException). Anyway, I'm getting somewhere: I realized I'm holding a reference to an object that was only partially constructed (the base class was constructed, then the derived class constructor threw the exception), and then I try to use that object. Still, that doesn't explain the bizarre debugger behavior.

Comment: *and then I try to use that object* -- Well once you did that, all bets are off as to how your program will behave.